# JMeter: @ notation (for xml)

Tags: groovy, jmeter, xml-parsing

On [groovy templates for jmeter page](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter/) there is an example I wanted to follow:

```
String xml = “
<actions>
 <action type=”error” info=”itsErrors”/>
 <action type="warning" info=”warnWarn”/>
 <action type=”info” info=”justLogInfo”/>
</actions>"

XmlParser parser = new XmlParser()
def actions= parser.parseText (xml)
actions.action.each { action ->
    println "${action.'@type'}: ${action.'@info'}";
}
```

At least in my JMeter 5.1 it did not work as posted, but when I fixed quotation marks it did:

```
String xml = """
<actions>
 <action type="error" info="itsErrors"/>
 <action type="warning" info="warnWarn"/>
 <action type="info" info="justLogInfo"/>
</actions>"""

XmlParser parser = new XmlParser()
def actions= parser.parseText (xml)
actions.action.each { action ->
    println "${action.'@type'}: ${action.'@info'}";
}
```

My question is usage of `@` mainly, dot and quotes too (`.'@type'`). I tried web search for Groovy @ and found nothing, for JMeter notations found https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html with only one instance of usage:

> Example: ${__XPath(/path/to/build.xml, //target/@name)} This will
>   match all targets in build.xml and return the contents of the next
>   name attribute

And about variables same link:

> Referencing a variable in a test element is done by bracketing the
>   variable name with '${' and '}'.

Groovy docs page for xml gives other notations:
https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

```
def text = '''
    <list>
        <technology>
            <name>Groovy</name>
        </technology>
    </list>
'''

def list = new XmlParser().parseText(text) 

assert list instanceof groovy.util.Node 
assert list.technology.name.text() == 'Groovy'
```

What each notation in `"${action.'@type'}: ${action.'@info'}"` means?

It isn't a JMeter variable even with `${}`, is it?
I managed to keep in working only w/put `'`, other parts seems necessary: `"`, `.`, `@`, `{}`, `$`. I may have put extra in last phrase, some I can explain, but just to be sure I understand it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [GPath](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) syntax used in groovy

> The most common way of querying XML in Groovy is using GPath
>
> For XML, you can also specify attributes, e.g.:
>
> `a["@href"]` → the href attribute of all the a elements
>
> `a.'@href'` → an alternative way of expressing this
>
> `a.@href` → an alternative way of expressing this when using XmlSlurper